# swift app battery very high and cpu min. 105%

Tags: ios

My swift 2 app have a very hight battery usage and a min. cpu of 105%
but first not the whole time.

1. I have an table view controller.
2. From there you can go to an camera controller - there you have to scan a barcode.
3. If the barcode was detected, a new view controller send the barcode via http post request to my mysql database and get informations.
4. this informations I will send to the last view controller. (this is my problem view controller, because there my cpu goes to min. 105% and the battery usage will be very high. from now in my complete app my cpu will be the whole time on min 105% - no matter which view controller will be the next.)

This is only a simple static table view, where the informations (2 Strings) will be shown. there you can click on "Save" and your entry will shown in the first table view controller.

I have delete all my code for the last view controller to make it blank.
no functions will be active in this controller.

But the cpu will goes up, too.
Any idea how can i check why the cpu goes up?

**UPDATE**

in my http post request controller (3)
is this code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
   self.LoadingCircle.rotate360Degrees(completionDelegate: self)
   self.isRotating = true
}
```

**rotate360Degress Extension**

```
extension UIView {
    func rotate360Degrees(duration: CFTimeInterval = 2.5, completionDelegate: AnyObject? = nil) {
        let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
        rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0)
        rotateAnimation.duration = duration

        if let delegate: AnyObject = completionDelegate {
            rotateAnimation.delegate = delegate
        }
        self.layer.addAnimation(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)
    }
}
```

if i delete the code in my viewWillAppear part, the cpu will stay "normal"

Comment: Can you provide same code or details of what are you doing?
Specially, image processing, animations, recursive codes, events...

Comment: okay, i found the code which is the problem part. i will update more information into my first post in a few seconds

Comment: This delegate is for...?

Comment: sorry? what do you mean? this extension animates an image, which I include in this view Controller - and rotates this 360 degrees

Comment: Do you repeat the animation when it stops? My question is what are you handling in the delegate functions

Comment: you are right. this was my mistake. i don't need this completionDelegate.
after removing this part of my extension - the cpu stay normal :) thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delegate in your case is unnecessary, actually it will cause this code to run in multiple instances, what will rise your CPU usage.

If you want to repeat the event, you can set the `.repeatCount = .infinity`

Comment: thanks for this note - but how can i stop the animation programmatically ?

Comment: You have to evoke removeAllAnimations(), I think in swift will be something like this, self.LoadingCircle.view.layer.removeAllAnimations()

Comment: okay i try self.LoadingCircle.layer.removeAllAnimations() (with view parameter it doesnt work) but the animation will not stop

Comment: okay, it will stop. but if this code part will execute, my image rotes 5-6 times more before it stops oO

Comment: I tested here calling in a button,         self.LoadingCircle.layer.removeAllAnimations()
and it works immediately, if you are having delay, try to call inside the main_queue,         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            self.LoadingCircle.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        }